# Could you let me know the differenct between 'of' and 'on''?

Tags: grammar

> If the evening 'of' the 18th has been booked up already, then what about lunch time on saturday the 20th?

Above is wrriten on my textbook, but I'm not sure why 'of' is used. I think we usually use 'on' with the specific date. What is the difference between 'of' and 'on' in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *on* instead of "of" here makes no sense because you are not saying "the evening" is happening on "the 18th."  You are talking about the point in time "evening of the 18th."

Think of *evening of the 18th* is a self-contained phrase of a point in time.  "Of the 18th" qualifies the word "evening" in that phrase.  The "of" does not link to anything outside of the phrase.

But, in the sentence above, it isn't talking about anything happening on that day/time (not directly, anyway).  It's talking about a specific day/time being "booked up."